# Why is my code for flood pixel area calculation timing out?

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, flood

I have made a flood map of Bangladesh following a tutorial. I am trying to determine the flood-affected land area by calculating pixel area. The map is displayed fine and the code for total area calculation of the geometry works fine as well.

But the calculation to determine flood-affected area times out and I cannot find alternative ways to do this. What is the error here?

```
// set Bangladesh as the target area
var bangladesh = admin0.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Bangladesh'))
var geometry = bangladesh.geometry();

var polarization = 'VH';

// load and filter Sentinel-1 GRD data
var collection= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')) 
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters',10))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .select([polarization])
  
// define date range to detect flood occurrence
var beforeStart = '2022-04-01'
var beforeEnd = '2022-04-30'
var afterStart = '2022-06-01'
var afterEnd = '2022-06-30'

// Print selected tiles to the console

      // Extract date from meta data
      function dates(imgcol){
        var range = imgcol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
        var printed = ee.String('from ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('min')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
          .cat(' to ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('max')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
        return printed;
      }

// select images by predefined dates
var beforeCollection = collection.filterDate(beforeStart, beforeEnd)
var afterCollection = collection.filterDate(afterStart,afterEnd)

// create a mosaic of selected tiles and clip to study area
var before = beforeCollection.mosaic().clip(geometry);
var after = afterCollection.mosaic().clip(geometry);

// apply a speckle filter (refined lee filter)
var beforeFiltered = ee.Image(toDB(RefinedLee(toNatural(before))))
var afterFiltered = ee.Image(toDB(RefinedLee(toNatural(after))))

// calculate the difference between the before and after images
var difference = afterFiltered.divide(beforeFiltered);

// define a threshold and create the flood extent mask
var diffThreshold = 1.25;
var diffBinary = difference.gt(diffThreshold);

// refine flood result using additional datasets
      
// include JRC layer on surface water seasonality to mask flood pixels from areas
// of permanent water (where there is water > 5 months of the year)
var permanentWater = gsw.select('seasonality').clip(geometry);
var permanentWaterMask = permanentWater.gte(5).updateMask(permanentWater.gte(5));
      
// flooded layer where permanent water bodies (water > 5 mo/yr) is assigned a 0 value
var floodedMask = diffBinary.where(permanentWaterMask,0);
// final flooded area without pixels in perennial waterbodies
var flooded = floodedMask.updateMask(floodedMask);
      
// compute connectivity of pixels to eliminate those connected to 8 or fewer neighbours
// this operation reduces noise of the flood extent product 
var connectedPixelThreshold = 8;
var connections = flooded.connectedPixelCount();    
var flooded = flooded.updateMask(connections.gte(connectedPixelThreshold));

// mask out areas with more than 5 percent slope using the HydroSHEDS DEM
var slopeThreshold = 5;
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(dem);
var slope = terrain.select('slope');
var flooded = flooded.updateMask(slope.lt(slopeThreshold));

// Calculate Affected Area
print('Total District Area (Ha)', geometry.area().divide(10000))

var stats = flooded.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
  tileScale: 16
})
print('Flooded Area (Ha)', ee.Number(stats.get('water')).divide(10000))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple errors. The below part of your code is not clear:

```
var beforeFiltered = ee.Image(toDB(RefinedLee(toNatural(before)))) 
var afterFiltered = ee.Image(toDB(RefinedLee(toNatural(after))))
```

Furthermore, selecting a big area can give such error of "time out". To solve this, you can select a smaller portion of your whole study area and replicate the calculation for each part. In your case, you replicate your calculations for each division or for half of the total divisions at a time.